# IdentityServer4 + ASP.NET core API + Angular: Login/authentication

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using IdentityServer4 to handle authentication and authorization in my ASP.NET core API. I use angular4 on client side.
I know that I can use token endpoint (http://myapidomain/connect/token) to get `access_token` by using grantype = `ResourceOwnerPassword`. It means that I provide `username` and `password` in login UI to authenticate.

My question is: do we need to implement API `Account/Login` anymore? I think that IdentityServer4 is already handle signin via cookie authentication middleware automatically.
If we need to implement API `Account/Login`. What is best practice to implement that.
I read somewhere is that use this for login

```
await  HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync(identityUser.Id,                                                                             identityUser.UserName);
```

and this for logout

```
await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync
```

The second question of mine is:
When I get `access_token` from `connect/token`. I try to get userinfo by access http://myapidomain/connect/userinfo. But I always get 405 error code.
What are my missing

in angular client

```
authFormHeaders() {
    const header = new Headers();
    header.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8');
    header.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    header.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.oidcSecurityCommon.getAccessToken());
    return header;
  }

getUserInfo() {
        let self = this;
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Get,
            headers: this.authService.authFormHeaders()
        });
        return self.http.get(this.authWellKnownEndpoints.userinfoEndpoint, options)
            .map((res: Response) => {
                return res.json();
            })
            .catch(self.appService.handleError);
    }
```

in my API server side:

```
CorsPolicyBuilder corsBuilder = new CorsPolicyBuilder()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowCredentials();
            services.AddCors(opts =>
            {
                opts.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", corsBuilder.Build());
            });

var url = optionsAccessor.Value.SystemConfig.Authority;
            app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = url,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                ApiName = "netpower.qms.saas.api"/*,
                AllowedScopes = { IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId }*/
            });
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
```

Answer (score 3):

For Angular client, should you be using grantype [Implicit](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/grant_types.html) and not [ResourceOwnerPassword](http://andyfiedler.com/2014/09/how-secure-is-the-oauth2-resource-owner-password-credential-flow-for-single-page-apps).The resource owner password credentials grant type is suitable in cases where the resource owner has a trust relationship with the client, such as the device operating system or a highly privileged application.
The authorization server should take special care when enabling this grant type and only allow it when other flows are not viable(From OAuth [Spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3))

> The resource owner password grant type allows to request tokens on
> behalf of a user by sending the user’s name and password to the token
> endpoint. This is so called “non-interactive” authentication and is
> generally not recommended. There might be reasons for certain legacy
> or first-party integration scenarios, where this grant type is useful,
> but the general recommendation is to use an interactive flow like
> implicit or hybrid for user authentication instead.

For implementation using Implicit,you can refer [this](https://damienbod.com/2015/11/08/oauth2-implicit-flow-with-angular-and-asp-net-5-identity-server/) and for using ResourceOwnerpassword ,refer [this](https://damienbod.com/2017/04/14/asp-net-core-identityserver4-resource-owner-password-flow-with-custom-userrepository/) .

The flow for Resource type is as follows

```
+----------+
 | Resource |
 |  Owner   |
 |          |
 +----------+
      v
      |    Resource Owner
     (A) Password Credentials
      |
      v
 +---------+                                  +---------------+
 |         |>--(B)---- Resource Owner ------->|               |
 |         |         Password Credentials     | Authorization |
 | Client  |                                  |     Server    |
 |         |<--(C)---- Access Token ---------<|               |
 |         |    (w/ Optional Refresh Token)   |               |
 +---------+                                  +---------------+
```

For ResourceOwnerPassword type with Angular and Identity Server 4,You can refer [this](https://github.com/robisim74/AngularSPAWebAPI/blob/master/EXPLANATION.md) GitHub repo which also contains some sample code for client and server side

The steps are as follows

1. The resource owner provides the client with its username and
   password.
2. The client requests an access token from the authorization
   server's token endpoint by including the credentials received
   from the resource owner.  When making the request, the client
   authenticates with the authorization server.
3. The authorization server authenticates the client and validates
   the resource owner credentials, and if valid, issues an access
   token.

**do we need to implement API Account/Login anymore?**

No you do not have to implement.As you suspected,this is done in the Authorization Server.You will send the user name and password to Identity Server 4 Authentication Server and that will be giving you the Bearer token.And your middleware (`app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication`) will authenticate the request for your application .

**I try to get userinfo by access http://myapidomain/connect/userinfo. But I always get 405 error code. What are my missing**

You can look into identity server logs to find out what is missing.I captured a sample requests and it will look like this

```
POST http://myapidomain/connect/token HTTP/1.1
Host: myapidomain
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 142
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://angularspawebapi.azurewebsites.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded


client_id=AngularSPA&grant_type=password&username=admin%40gmail.com&password=Admin01*&scope=WebAPI%20offline_access%20openid%20profile%20roles


GET http://myapidomain/connect/userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: myapidomain
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjhDRTQ1ODAwQTAwNkExNkZGMzEwOTExMDVCRjNDNTY2MzgzNEUxQkEiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiJqT1JZQUtBR29XX3pFSkVRV19QRlpqZzA0Ym8ifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1MDAwOTk4NjIsImV4cCI6MTUwMDEwMDc2MiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDovL2FuZ3VsYXJzcGF3ZWJhcGkuYXp1cmV3ZWJzaXRlcy5uZXQiLCJhdWQiOlsiaHR0cDovL2FuZ3VsYXJzcGF3ZWJhcGkuYXp1cmV3ZWJzaXRlcy5uZXQvcmVzb3VyY2VzIiwiV2ViQVBJIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6IkFuZ3VsYXJTUEEiLCJzdWIiOiI5Y2I1ZGViNS1iZWRmLTRkMWItOThkNS05ZTFjYTgwNzVhYjAiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1MDAwOTk4NjEsImlkcCI6ImxvY2FsIiwicm9sZSI6ImFkbWluaXN0cmF0b3IiLCJzY29wZSI6WyJvcGVuaWQiLCJwcm9maWxlIiwicm9sZXMiLCJXZWJBUEkiLCJvZmZsaW5lX2FjY2VzcyJdLCJhbXIiOlsicHdkIl19.CZAGtK5hvwgkMvX9NQ-8zTFr8Cv3SRVhM-u1WdqdLwI-qbdknfhhVFFHFpPzEWEJnKhsi3aE_BOb_UtRiDBWNHzlXAGmKSjtd70HOlT3dR9Sj_v09Ld15On3HihgfeDwOzIt10ZYwwjRr1tRCf6Ro41FQ2UrzBYcSFe47md7DSlxPXbjnQAHdu8gHMITFF8Nqx0V9OEw21fofRdBalOpvxf1IBhsJwWLyL4bLFYya8jNispK4MnN_tdaS8kxIMZ8iC_IUlhY4XEj5pkDBA9r8ad_Vn5WavO3Lmr4Tew4uBhlFhbE-Qr6EpErAEBVHVtJYs70XXGJJ7QQLoFNmO5M9w
content-type: text/plain
```

Comment: Thank you for response. So do we need to implement login API?

Comment: I think you are over-playing the "don't use ResourceOwnerPassword flow" card. As your quoted text says, it is a suitable flow for first-party integration and in particular provides a cleaner UX when you own the client, the api, the identity server and they are your users. Sure you don't want 3rd party clients using that flow for *your* users, but I disagree that the trust relationship with the client needs to be 'highly privileged' or operating system level.

Comment: @Mashton ,I did not make it up out of thin air.It is there in the OAuth [Spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.3)

Comment: Thank @RohithRajan for your reply. It very helpful information. If IdentityServer handle authentication, so how can we set cookie/token expire? Do we control expire token on server side or client side?

Comment: by default ,the bearer token you receive will have expiry timeout. And you need to implement refresh token mechanism. IdentityServer allows you to refresh the token with another rest call, Even that implementation is there in the linked GitHub repo.

Comment: @RohithRajan: Hi again, can you help me to figure out how to make userinfo endpoint work?
I spent more than a week to make userinfo endpoint work, but could not. I have no idea what are my missing. :(

Comment: @RohithRajan: yes, I still get 405 error.
I configure Cors on server side and also add bearer token on client side.
Not sure what are my missing :(

Comment: To verify everything is working fine for ,please try the following code  from [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/2_resource_owner_passwords.html)  // request token
var tokenClient = new TokenClient(disco.TokenEndpoint, "ro.client", "secret");
var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync("alice", "password", "api1");

if (tokenResponse.IsError)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Error);
    return;
}

Console.WriteLine(tokenResponse.Json);
Console.WriteLine("\n\n");

Comment: @RohithRajan: thank you very much. Finally, I can make it working by putting app.UseCors("xxx"); before app.UseIdentityServer(); in Configure method.
Of courses, we need to implement ICorsPolicyService.
Thank you again.